# PGFplots with row wise plot with .dat file

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I have the following data.dat file, which looks like this

```
n  1   2  3  4
L1 11  7  13 14
L2 52  61 17 18
L3 9   10 11 12
```

I want to plot make a plot of L1 (y-axis) against n (x-axis). The same question was asked in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240386/plot-data-row-wise-with-pgfplots) and was solved, but I don't follow the answer.

Specifically, is there any way to achieve this without adding a default column to the data as suggested in the linked post? I am importing the above data using `\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}{\data}`

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}   

\begin{document} 
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}{\data}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[width=\columnwidth,
        height=0.618\columnwidth,
        clip bounding box=upper bound,
        xlabel style = {font=\large, yshift=-0.5ex},
        ylabel style = {font=\large, yshift=-0.5ex},
        xlabel={$n$},
        ylabel={L1},
        \pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=n]\datatable{\data},
        ]
        \addplot [black, line width=0.8pt] table [x={colnames}, y={L1}] {\datatable};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However this does not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not use the key in the intended way, but according to what I find all you need to do is to

- use `\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=<col>]\datatable{\loadedtable}`, where `col` is the name of the column that you want to use for `x`, say.
- in the plot use `x=<col>`.

That is, `<col>` gets mapped to `colnames` and `pgfplots` can use it as a valid column name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\pgfplotstableread{
n  1   2  3  4
L1 11  7  13 14
L2 52  61 17 18
L3 9   10 11 12
}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=n]\datatable{\loadedtable}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\datatable
\caption{Table.}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \pgfplotstableread{
        n  1   2  3  4
        L1 11  7  13 14
        L2 52  61 17 18
        L3 9   10 11 12
      }\loadedtable
      \pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=n]\datatable{\loadedtable}

      \addplot table[x=colnames,y=L1] {\datatable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot.}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It works the same with data files. (Note that there have been some recent changes on `filecontents`, so if you get errors this may be because now it seems to have become *harder* to overwrite files. That is, you may have some old file in the directory, which gets loaded and causes errors.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
n  1   2  3  4
L1 11  7  13 14
L2 52  61 17 18
L3 9   10 11 12
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=n]\datatable{\loadedtable}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\datatable
\caption{Table.}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\loadedtable
      \pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=n]\datatable{\loadedtable}

      \addplot table[x=colnames,y=L1] {\datatable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot.}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I edit your code to work with importing data, using `\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}{\data}`

Comment: Specifically, see the MWE in the updated question

Comment: @Sid It works in the same way, please see the update.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am getting a LaTeX warning: `Redefining document command \PR with arg. spec. ' >{ \SplitArgument{1}{|} }`

Comment: Apologies, the code was working fine. I have accepted the answer. The error was the encoding in my input data file. I was generating data from Matlab and somehow, I was getting UTF-8 encoded data in my data.dat file.