# Reading `xticklabels` from file: comma's do not split

Tags: pgfplots, datatool, axis

The following is a MWE of a plot reading the `xticklabels` from  a file. It works, but the comma's inside the string that is fetched from the file, don't split the string into multiple parts. How do we remove the group around the string that is fetched?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, datatool, filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myfile.tex}
xticklabels:-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5
\end{filecontents}
\DTLsetseparator{:}
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{mydata}{mydata.extra}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick = {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
        xticklabels = \DTLfetch{mydata}{key}{xticklabels}{value},
    ]
    \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The top image is what we get, and the bottom image is what I expect.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgfplots`, with its companion package `pgfplotstable`, already has the ability to read data from file. (And I guess/think `datatool` has some compatibility issue with `pgfplots`.)

In the following example,

- Data is written in `mydata.tex` by row, and separated by comma.
- Data is stored in command `\mydata`.

  - Since `pgfplots` reads data by column, `\pgfplotstabletranspose` is used to transpose the data matrix.
  - By default, `\pgfplotstabletranspose` creates new column names. Options `colnames from={xticklabels}, input colnames to={xticklabels}` make it use `xticklabels` as column name.
- Option `xticklabels from table={\mydata}{xticklabels}` uses data from table `\mydata`, column `xticklabels` as `xticklabels` list.

Related questions:

- [table transpose](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288547/79060)
- [Plot data row-wise with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240386/79060)
- [Pgfplotstable without headings row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67542/79060)

```
\begin{filecontents}[force, noheader]{mydata.tex}
xticklabels,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % transpose data table
  \pgfplotstabletranspose[
    colnames from={xticklabels}, 
    input colnames to={xticklabels}
  ]{\mydata}{mydata.tex}
  
  \begin{axis}[
      xtick = {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
      xticklabels from table={\mydata}{xticklabels},
  ]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### As a response to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557294/reading-xticklabels-from-file-commas-do-not-split/557318?noredirect=1#comment1405223_557318)

In case one wants to have syntax `xticklabels=<macro storing a list>`, see the following patch

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
% redefine pgfplots key "xticklabels", expand its value once before parsing
\pgfkeys{
    /pgfplots/xticklabels/.code={%
        \expandafter\pgfplotslistnew\expandafter\pgfplots@xticklabels\expandafter{#1}%
        \let\pgfplots@xticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x
    }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\xticklabels{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xtick = {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
      xticklabels=\xticklabels,
  ]
    \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative solution using `pgfplotstable`. I was aware of this package but actually interested in a solution without using a different package. Appearantly even `xticklabels = \xticklabels` with `\newcommand\xticklabels{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}` does not work. Why not?

Comment: @Carucel Because key `xticklabels` is defined such that its value is not expanded before being parsed as a list.

Comment: @Carucel To support syntax `xticklabels=<macro storing a list>`, I've added a new example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to expand all? `\newcommand\xticklabelsB{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}\newcommand\xticklabels{\xticklabelsB}` does not work using your solution.

Comment: @Carucel It's feasible, for example use `\expandafter\pgfplotslistnew\expandafter\pgfplots@xticklabels\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}`. Be care because this requires the ticklabel list being fully expandable. Alternatively, you can expand `\xticklabelsB` when defining `\xticklabels`, `\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter\xticklabels\expandafter{\xticklabelsB}`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `\expanded` doesn't work with `\DTLfetch` though, because it is [not expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335489/32291).